# html2canvas to render document PDF with css styling using angular2/typescript

Tags: pdf, angular, typescript, html2canvas

How to generate an output file PDF using html2canvas with angular2

I tried to import the file html2canvas typescript and made a declaration like this to use it

```
declare let html2canvas: Html2CanvasStatic;
```

but I get html2canvas is not defined

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

I found this file typescript on github [html2canvas typescript](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/html2canvas/html2canvas.d.ts)

how can use this for my application angular2

Answer (score 15):

I could use html2canvas with the followings changes:

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
     "html2canvas": "0.5.0-beta4",
     "@types/html2canvas": "0.5.32",
 }
```

After using `npm install` I could use html2canvas in my component.ts files like this:

```
import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas"

test() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL()
        window.open(img);
     }
    });
```

}

Without installing `@types/html2canvas`I could use the lib via require but not via the import:

```
html2canvas = require('hmtl2canvas');
```

Comment: do we need to import html2canvas script in index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Angular 4 you can include html2canvas under scripts list in **.angular-cli.json**  as below

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js"
]
```

After that import it in your class as below

```
import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas"
```

and then use it in your functions as below

```
html2canvas(parameters);
```

Comment: If you use a global script import via angular-cli.json *don't* import it in your component as you'll load it twice : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Answer (score 4):

In 2018:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
    window.open().document.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in addition to above answer, i.e. add @types/html2canvas to dependencies and add import statement in your code.

However, using the above sample code, I am getting error in VisualStudioCode i.e.

> 'onrendered' does not exist in type 'Html2CanvasOptions'.

To resolve that, I used "then" as below:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myClickFunction(event: any) {
html2canvas(event.target)
  .then((canvas) => {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL()
    window.open(img);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("error canvas", err);
  });
}
```