# Angular 2 - Import html2canvas

Tags: node.js, angular, import, npm, html2canvas

I have installed `html2canvas` on my `angular 2` project using `npm install html2canvas --save`. If I now go to any file and write `import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas'` it gives the error:

```
Cannot find module 'html2canvas'
```

My package file looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

The file on which I'm trying to import the `html2canvas` is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Injectable ()
export class pdfGeneratorService {

  ...
}
```

Comment: You need to install the typings for it too.

Comment: Ah yeah that's it. If you could make it a answer, I'll set it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Angular2 uses typescript, you need to install the typescript definition files for that module.

It can be installed from `@types` (if it exists). If it doesn't you can create your own definition file and include it in your project.

Answer (score 3):

in angular 9 i use it this way:

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
....
    html2canvas(this.head2print.nativeElement).then(_canvas => {
      hdr = _canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    });
```

Comment: What version of html2canvas are you using? I am building an angular 13 project and version 1.0.0-rc.1 works, but I can't get version 1.3 or 1.4 working. I need newer functionality render svg objects.

Comment: i upgraded app to every angular version since then, also upgraded html2canvas..... right now angular version 13.1 and html2canvas 1.3.3 if you need source code I can post that part, but I think it is very similar to that above, I dont remember that I had big problems while switching between versions.... I use it to produce large table image that I send to C# backend where I make custom pdf report on several pages with headers and footers.

Comment: I tested it right now, and that code above still works ok, but I switched to "html-to-image" ver. 1.9 hoped to be faster, but didnt notice any change in speed:

htmlToImage.toPng(this.head2print.nativeElement).then(_dataUrl => {
      hdr = _dataUrl;
});

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with version 1.1 which has the svg support I need. I wasn't able to get the latest to work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the **onrendered** option for callback function may not work. Instead, you may use "then" as below:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366038/3119507

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue running Angular 8. It still didn't work after installing the **@types**. What worked for me was to include the html2canvas library using require instead.

```
const html2canvas = require('../../../node_modules/html2canvas');
```

Then to take the screenshot:

```
       @ViewChild('screenshotCanvas') screenCanvas: ElementRef;

       html2canvas(this.screenCanvas.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            console.log("ENTER takeScreenshot: ",imgData )
            document.body.appendChild(imgData);
        })
```

Comment: +1 I don't like this way of importing but this is the only way working so far after hours of searching and tinkering.