# html2canvas in Angular - Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, typescript, types, html2canvas

I am trying to use the html2canvas library into an Angular 8 project.

I also tried to install the html2canvas types in my project by `npm install --save @types/html2canvas` but it stills not working.

Template:

```
<div #myform>
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf-viewer',
  templateUrl: './pdf-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdf-viewer.component.scss']
})
export class PdfViewerComponent {
  @ViewChild('myform', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) pdfForm: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}


  pdfDownload() {
    html2canvas(this.pdfForm.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
  }

}
```

My intention is to render the form as canvas, but the application throws the error:

**ERROR in src/app/grid/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.ts (19,5): error TS2349: Can not invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import ("myroute")' you have not supported call signatures.**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solved! Thank you :)

Finally I imported in that way:

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

Comment: Worked like charm, Thanks a lot bro!

Answer (score 7):

For Angular 8, see this link: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1896#issuecomment-506129710

Basically, you need to have version 1.0.0-rc.1 of html2canvas installed for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Angular 8 and the only way I was able to import the library without errors was using require.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57174935/3792636).

Comment: As I said, for me now it's working with "import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';"

Comment: yup I know @Jgascona,Just giving another option for other people having the same issue that may come across this SO as your solution did not wok for me.

Comment: Thanks for that @velval, hope some of the answer could be usefull for someone

Comment: This is the only way I managed to solve it. I'm running on Angular `8.2.14` and html2canvas `1.0.0-rc.5`