# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html2canvas'

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I get the following error when trying to compile. Please help.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html2canvas'

Comment: may be you have not installed `html2canvas`, try to run npm install again

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998844/html2canvas-to-render-document-pdf-with-css-styling-using-angular2-typescript

Comment: I have tried all this. I have uninstalled, reinstalled. I have changed versions. None of this works. There has to be something else.

Comment: Did you find any solution?I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Install html2canvas and its typings with following commands

npm install --save html2canvas

npm install --save @types/html2canvas